# How to handle Jquery custom funtions undefined scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I defined a custom funtion in jquery like below

```
 jQuery.predictiveTextInit = function (obj, options) {
    //do something 
}
```

and i am calling the funtion like below

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        assignselectedvalues();
    })
    function getpredictions_c(e, selector, loc) {
        localStorage['SearchCache'] = "";
        $(".myInputContainer2").hide();
        var hdnPredictiveval = $('#hdnPredictiveURL').val();
        var formatselector = "." + selector;
        var formatloc = "." + loc; //".searchCommunityLocation";//"." + loc;
        var ptObj = { url: hdnPredictiveval, suggestContainer: formatselector };
        $.predictiveTextInit($(formatloc), ptObj);
        $(".searchCommunityLocation").val(e.target.value);
    }
</script>
```

html

```
 <input type="text" class="@searchCommunityLocation" onkeyup="getpredictions_c(event,'@dynamicContainer','@searchCommunityLocation')" name="searchCommunityLocation" id="searchCommunityLocation"/>
```

but some times i am getting error saying like  $.predictiveTextInit is not a function but sometimes works fine what could be reason?

thanks in advance

Comment: Blind guess - sometimes the function is added to jQuery, other times it's not. Possibly because of async loading of scripts. It's very hard to say exactly what is happening without a [mcve] or more details.

Comment: Where are you calling getpredictions_c() ? Make sure it is called AFTER document is ready and all JS/JQuery is already loaded.

Comment: even i suspected that but i calling that funtion when page is loaded (when user types in text box) so async won't be a issue i guess

Comment: I would put a `console.log` before both lines and when the error appears see if they were called in the correct order.